# Filtering only matched data from query result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document where I have user array. Inside user array I have cars array.
I want to filter out only the portion of document which matches my query.

I have tried adding filter, but does not seem to be returning the right results.

This is my document, which contains two users.
Each user will have couple of cars.

```
{
  "group": "fans",
  "user": [
    {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Paul",
      "cars": [
        {
          "model": "deyatona",
          "make": "ferrari"
        },
        {
          "model": "gallardo",
          "make": "lamborghini"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "first": "Papa",
      "last": "Jones",
      "cars": [
        {
          "model": "Q7",
          "make": "audi"
        },
        {
          "model": "250 gt",
          "make": "ferrari"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
---
Here is my search query:
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "user.first": "John"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "user.cars",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "user.cars.make": "ferrari"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


===>
This obviously returns the whole document.

I want to filter out only the following part which matches the query:
{
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Paul",
      "cars": [
        {
          "model": "deyatona",
          "make": "ferrari"
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {
        "name": "outer",
        "_source": ["user.first", "user.last"]
      }, 
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "user.first": "John"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "inner_hits": {}, 
                "path": "user.cars",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "user.cars.make": "ferrari"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant, it still gives me both the sections.

Comment: I was going through some blogs and it seemed that multi level "inner_hits" does not work. Is my understanding correct ?

On root level it works perfectly fine as per bellow example:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html

Comment: Forgot to add inner_hit in parent. Updated query to make it work and ignore extra details.

Comment: Cool Nishant, I also could find it out with your previous help. Thanks, cheers.